# how to apply dcast on multiple dataframes in r

Tags: r

I have 31 dataframes in r from df1 to df31

```
df1

make   type    qty

df2

make   type    qty
abc    def     10
dde    ert     3 

df3

make   type    qty
rty    r45      78
```

I want to dcast it to following

```
make   type    qty    make_1    type_1    qty_1   
 NA     NA      NA     NA        NA        NA       
 abc    def     10     dde       ert       3 
 rty    r45     78     NA        NA        NA
```

How can I do it for all dataframes together in r ?

This is my dataframe structure

```
  dput(dredge_cutter1)
  structure(list(Make = character(0), Type = character(0), Qty. = 
  numeric(0)), .Names = c("Make", 
  "Type", "Qty."), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame")
  > dput(dredge_cutter5)
  structure(list(Make = "SHRIYAM", Type = "FLARRED", Qty. = 3), .Names = 
  c("Make", 
  "Type", "Qty."), row.names = 2L, class = "data.frame")
  > dput(dredge_cutter23)
  structure(list(Make = c("SHRIYAM", "SHRIYAM"), Type = c("FLARED", 
  "CHISEL POINT"), Qty. = c(15, 2)), .Names = c("Make", "Type", 
   "Qty."), row.names = 2:3, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The first dataset is not clear.  Is it a vector or data.frame with 0 rows?

Comment: @ its a empty dataframe. with zero rows

Comment: Please edit your post with dput output so that we know the structure

Comment: Your column name is different.  So, you need to change `value.var = c("Make", "Type", "Qty.")` in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be

```
library(data.table)
res <- rbindlist(lapply(mget(paste0("df", 1:3)), function(x) {
   x <- if(nrow(x)==0) data.frame(setNames(replicate(3, NA, simplify = FALSE),
      names(x))) else x
     dcast(as.data.table(x)[, n := seq_len(.N)],
          1~n, value.var = c("Make", "Type", "Qty."))}),
          fill = TRUE)[,-1, with = FALSE]


setnames(res, make.unique(sub("_\\d+", "", names(res)), sep="_"))[]
#      Make    Type Qty.  Make_1       Type_1 Qty._1
#1:      NA      NA   NA      NA           NA     NA
#2: SHRIYAM FLARRED    3      NA           NA     NA
#3: SHRIYAM  FLARED   15 SHRIYAM CHISEL POINT      2
```

Comment: I get following error when I run above code.. `Error: value.var (maketypeqty) not found in input In addition: Warning message:
In if (!(value.var %in% names(data))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: @Neil  I assumed your `df1` as `df1 <- data.frame(make=character(0),   type = character(0), 
    qty=numeric(0), stringsAsFactors= FALSE)`

Comment: `Error in value_vars(value.var, names(data)) : 
  value.var values [c("make", "type", "qty"), NULL, NULL] are not found in 'data'.`

Comment: @Neil Could you update your post with the dput of df1, df2, df3 as I am not getting any errors

Comment: when I run first two lines of your code it gives me following error. `Error in rbindlist(lapply(mget(paste0("dredge_cutter", 1:31)), function(x) { : 
  Item 1 of list input is not a data.frame, data.table or list`

Comment: @Neil I updated with the datasets I used and also changed the code a bit

Comment: When I run your code with your dataframes its giving me all `NA's`

Comment: @Neil Sorry, last time I updated, for some reason the `if/else` condition got removed.  Updated the post based on the new example

Comment: Awesome, now its working fine, thanks a ton for your time and effort.